When I run `go test -fuzz=Fuzz`, Not enough memory resources are available to process this command
When I was doing fuzz testing in Go according to the examples in the documentation, I got this error.
error log
$ go test -fuzz=Fuzz
warning: the test binary was not built with coverage instrumentation, so fuzzing will run without coverage guidance and may be inefficient
--- FAIL: FuzzReverse (0.01s)
mapping temporary file C:\Users\use\AppData\Local\Temp\fuzz-2637883721: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    example/fuzz    0.031s
my code
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func FuzzReverse(f *testing.F) {
    testcases := []string{"Hello, world", " ", "!12345"}
    for _, tc := range testcases {
        f.Add(tc) // Use f.Add to provide a seed corpus
    }
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, orig string) {
        rev := Reverse(orig)
        doubleRev := Reverse(rev)
        if orig != doubleRev {
            t.Errorf("Before: %q, after: %q", orig, doubleRev)
        }
        if utf8.ValidString(orig) && !utf8.ValidString(rev) {
            t.Errorf("Reverse produced invalid UTF-8 string %q", rev)
        }
    })
}

and test log
$ go test
PASS
ok      example/fuzz    0.027s
$ go version
go version go1.23.0 windows/386

You need a larger computer.

@Volker It needs to run Go, though.

No, my system has 32G memory, my system is Windows 11, and when I was running the test, I was observing the memory usage, and I did not find a sudden increase in memory usage to cause insufficient memory.

I used another Win11 computer with 16G memory and encountered the same error.

Sorry, I downloaded and used go version go1.23.0 windows/386 by mistake. I used echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% to check my CPU architecture as amd64. After I reinstalled the go language for amd64 and checked go env, my fuzzy query no longer reported this error. And it is consistent with the document results. Very important sentence: Go fuzzing with coverage instrumentation is only available on AMD64 and ARM64 architectures currently.

I doubt/suspect that your Reverse(orig) function returns an error but you ignore it. If your function returns an error like:
func Reverse(s string) (string, error) {
if !utf8.ValidString(s) {
    return s, errors.New("input is not valid UTF-8")
}
r := []rune(s)
for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
    r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
}
return string(r), nil
}

Then your test should look like:
func FuzzReverse(f *testing.F) {
testcases := []string{"Hello, world", " ", "!12345"}
for _, tc := range testcases {
    f.Add(tc) // Use f.Add to provide a seed corpus
}
f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, orig string) {
    rev := Reverse(orig)
    if err1 != nil {
        t.Skip()
    }
    doubleRev, err2 := Reverse(rev)
    if err2 != nil {
        t.Skip()
    }
    if orig != doubleRev {
        t.Errorf("Before: %q, after: %q", orig, doubleRev)
    }
    if utf8.ValidString(orig) && !utf8.ValidString(rev) {
        t.Errorf("Reverse produced invalid UTF-8 string %q", rev)
    }
})
}

Also make sure your main package's folder is writable and you may need to clean the cache if the issue still persists:
Running 'go clean -fuzzcache' removes all cached fuzzing values. This may make fuzzing less effective, temporarily.

I advise to go through the doc step by step avoiding jumping/skipping some steps or just copying the code without reading the instructions & explanations as it's useful for avoiding such unknown errors. LMK more details and/or share your full code including the function itself that you're testing (the fuzz target).
PS: You may find the following commands useful:
go help testflag
go help testflag

You may additionally find this link useful!

My go env, where GOARCH=386. I noticed that the documentation says Go fuzzing with coverage instrumentation is only available on AMD64 and ARM64 architectures currently. Could this be the reason?
